# How to retrieve localStorage data from safari extension to webpage?

Tags: safari

I just developing safari extension for an app in that i have a normal signup and signin functionality. When i signin iam just storing token in local storage. My problem is not able to get local storage data from safari extension to global page.for example i was just place a button in webpage when i click the button i need a token from local storage stored in safari extension popover. Both webpage and safari extension popover local storage is different. when i try to get token from webpage it producing null reference.how can i achieve this?

Comment: pls help me anyone till now can't get solution